# Primefaces isn't working in mode advance jsf 2.0

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, camunda

I'm trying to upload file using primefaces 4.0 in jsf 2.0.
After I config pom.xml and web.xml and it can work with mode="simple" and I can choose a file well.
My problem is upload multiple file in mode="advance", it display a upload panel in UI but javascript not  working.
I don't add any js lib in my jsf page to escape conflict with primefaces js.
Do you have any recommend related?

In the case I can't use primefaces with mode="advance" then what should i use to upload multiple file in jsf 2.0?

Please help.
 - XHTML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{helloBean.upload}"
            mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false" multiple="true"
            sizeLimit="100000" fileLimit="3"
            allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

- ManageBean

  ```
  @ManagedBean
  @SessionScoped
  public class HelloBean implements Serializable {

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      private String destination = "E:\\uploadFile\\";

      private UploadedFile file;

      public void upload(FileUploadEvent event) {
          System.out.println(event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
      }

      public UploadedFile getFile() {
          return file;
      }

      public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
          this.file = file;
      }

  }
  ```
- web.xml

  ```
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- ############################################# -->
  <!-- # File upload                               # -->
  <!-- ############################################# -->
  <filter>
      <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>
          org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter
      </filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  </filter-mapping>
  ```
- pom.xml:

  ```
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
          <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
          <version>4.0</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
          <version>2.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
          <version>1.2</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.7</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.7</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
          <version>1.2</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.5</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
          <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
      <finalName>JavaServerFaces</finalName>

      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.3.1</version>
              <configuration>
                  <source>1.6</source>
                  <target>1.6</target>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
  ```
- library: i add commons-fileupload-1.2.jar, commons-fileupload-1.2-sources.jar, commons-io-2.4.jar,
  commons-io-2.4-sources.jar, primefaces-4.0.jar, primefaces-4.0-sources.jar.
- Error show from firebug:

  ```
  TypeError: $(...).addclass is not a function
  $(this).addclass('ui-state-focus');
  ```

  The error happen below file.
  **http:/.../JavaServerFaces/javax.faces.resource/fileupload/fileupload.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=4.0**

I already upload with mode="simple" successful but not success with mode="advance".
What's i missing?

Comment: p:fileUpload in simple mode did not support multiple files upload. You should select advance in case upload multiple. Please post all your code which use mode="advance".

Comment: hi,
I know mode="simple" do not support for upload multiple file.
My mean is add a <p:upload mode="simple"> each time user click "add upload" command button.
It'll reload page and <ui:repeat> will show list <p:upload mode="simple">
This way also can upload multiple file but disadvantage is reload page each time cliking command button. 
how can i do it and not load jsf page again?  
Source code i will post on tommorow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to submit form to iframe. Because of `p:fileUpload` mode="simple" must work with submit form. This proposed can solve reload page on browser.

The example code below.
XHTML

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" target="my_iframe">
    <p:fileUpload value="#{fileUploadView.file}" mode="simple" />
    <p:commandButton value="Submit" 
                     ajax="false" 
                     actionListener="#{fileUploadView.upload}" />        
</h:form>
<iframe name="my_iframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

ManagedBean

```
@ManagedBean
public class FileUploadView {

    private UploadedFile file;
    public void upload() {
        if(file != null) {
            System.out.println(file.getFileName());
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub           
        }
    }

    public UploadedFile getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
}
```

This an example of multiple file upload by using mode="advance"

XHTML

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">          
    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadView.handleFileUpload}" 
                  mode="advanced" 
                  dragDropSupport="false" 
                  multiple="true" 
                  update="@this"
                  process="@this" 
                  sizeLimit="100000" 
                  fileLimit="3" 
                  allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" /> 
</h:form>
```

ManagedBean

```
@ManagedBean
public class FileUploadView {

    private UploadedFile file;

    public UploadedFile getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I will consider it.
Could you please send me any simple upload source code with mode="advance"?
The xhtml just need have form upload.
I want to reference.
Thanks

Comment: @JavaDeveloper try to change commons-fileupload,commons-io to version 1.2.1, 1.4 respectively because those version are tested and known to be working with PrimeFaces 4.0, and also remove commons-fileupload-1.2-sources.jar, commons-io-2.4-sources.jar, primefaces-4.0-sources.jar from you dependency.

Comment: Hi,
Advance mode have 3 button: choose, upload and cancel.
I select an file and click upload button then it look like submit whole form.
In scenario i have a form with 10 input field, an upload panel and a submit form.
When i click upload button, it submit whole form and do also submit function.
Can we have a way let upload button just do handle "handleFileUpload" for only the upload file?
So when i click submit button then that's the time to submit whole form.

Comment: In generally, p:fileUpload in mode="advance" not submit whole form. how do you set update attribute. I apologize with my example, it should use process="@this" and process="@this" in case update and process itself. By those 2 attribute, your from should not submit whole form.

Comment: Now, I update my XHTML in mode="advance". Good luck.

Comment: Hi,
I create a form with some input field a upload panel(mode advance).
I choose some upload file but i don't click upload buton.
I click submit form then no file upload.
How can i upload file with no click upload button?

Comment: @JavaDeveloper, please create "How can i upload file with no click upload button" into new topic of question because the question not related to current topic, and answers of the question require good answers would be example code.